# Pronunciation of unstressed vowels

Tags: pronunciation

In San Duanmu's Standard Chinese phonology it goes over unstressed vowels and mentions that they change in unstressed syllables. e.g.

a, e, (a, ɤ) > ə  [报上 pau ʂaŋ > pau ʐəŋ]
ou > o [木头 muthou > muto]
ai > ɛ [脑袋 nau tai > nau dɛ]
ao (au) > ɔ [知道 ʈ͡ʂɻ tau >  ʈ͡ʂɻ dɔ or ʈ͡ʂɻ ɔ]

However, there wasn't much detail on when which unstressed syllables these occur and I have seen some other changes not mentioned or different to those above:

ei > i
ao > ɑ [多少 two ʂau > two ʂɑ or two ɑ ]

Are there any definitive guides on how these should be pronounced in colloquial speech? I'm sure it varies by region though so are there any patterns in Beijing dialect?

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is actually a feature of Beijing mandarin. Vowel unstressing occurs when the syllable is 轻声 tone.
In the pronunciation of "model pronouncers" like news commentators, this phenomenon, along with even 轻声, is minimized.